# Fedora adb issues with USB

Tags: android

I've already looked at many different articles
and nothing is working for me.

I have an older Fedora 10 and this is what I get
with my phone attached with USB:

```
[root@localhost ~]# adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
```

Also nothing from 'adb devices'

No adb processes are running

I created '51-android.rules':

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0fce", SYMLINK+="android_adb", MODE="0666"
```

and it has root Read and Write permissions.

Does the xx-android.rules matter?  I've seen some others
use something different.

Also, USB Debugging is enabled on the device.

Is there anything else I can try?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you see the little "usb debugging" icon in your phone's notification area?

Comment: No, I don't think I see it.  I tried un-checking and re-checking it and I don't see anything in the notification area, I'm using a Sony Xperia Miro with 4.0.1 on it.  That looks like a little pitch fork like icon? Nope..

Comment: I just found something.  It has an unusual setting:  Xperia->Connectivity->USB connection mode->"Media transfer mode(MTP)" or "Mass storage mode(MSC)".  MSC info says ".. and MAC OS/Linux computers lacking MTP support"  It says that MTP is the default.

Comment: Try any different modes available, sometimes the "default" one is unable to connect to USB debugging